# Regex for positive number, with two float number, not leading zero

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write validation for number input.
Accepted numbers:
0,21
0
0,3
78,21
8934

Not Allowed:
00
0,323
-1
021

Comment: Please include a question. I suppose you have tried to actually write the validation? What is wrong/not working as expected? See [ask] a question with an [mcve]. Also, there may allready be an handfull of older posts on SO regarding this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Try pattern `^(?:0,\d\d?|[1-9]\d*(?:,\d\d?)?|0|)$`

Explanation:

`^` - match beginning of string

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`0,\d\d?` - match literally `0,` and then match one or two digits

`|` - alternation (match pattern on the right side OR on the left side)

`[1-9]\d*(?:,\d\d?)?` - match non-zero digit `[1-9]`, then match zero or more digits `\d*`, then optionally (due to `?` operator at the end) `,\d\d?`, so comma followed by one or two digits

`0` - match `0` literally

`(?:...|)` - last option in alternation matches empty string

`$` - match end of string

```js
var myArray = ['0,21', '78,21', '8934', '', '00', '0,323', '-1', '021', '0,3', '1,3', '0'];
for(var i of myArray)
    console.log(`${i} matches: ${/^(?:0,\d\d?|[1-9]\d*(?:,\d\d?)?|0|)$/.test(i)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more extensible method than regex

```js
const okNum = ["0,21","78,21","8934",""]
const notOk = ["00","0,323","-1","021"]

const validNum = str => {
  if (str.trim() === "") { console.log(str,"empty ok, passed"); return true; }
  const num = str.replace(",",".")
  let testNum = parseFloat(num)
  if (testNum<0) { console.log(str,"negative, failed"); return false; }
  if (testNum.toString().includes(".")) {  
    testNum = +testNum.toFixed(2)
  }
  else {
    if (testNum.toString() !== str) { console.log(str,"not same length, failed"); return false }
  }
  console.log(+num,testNum,+num === testNum?"passed":"failed")
  return +num === testNum
};
okNum.map(num => validNum(num))
notOk.map(num => validNum(num))
```